# How To generate Image Using Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, image, magento2.4.5

I have a requirement to generate image and PDF using Magento2 , currently I have generated the Pdf file using custom data with the same content I need to create an image file also in png format.

Can anyone help me to do this, or can we convert the generated PDF file to png format?

Magento version : 2.4.5